# Detox e2e build doesnt display any styling or images

Tags: reactjs, react-native, detox

I have had my fair share of detox today - I'm sitting with an issue where I create a build for detox to create e2e testing with `detox build--configuration android` and then running `detox test --configuration android` to run my tests, the CSS and Images do not display and Detox then says that there are no visible elements that it can target and bombs out because the test cant proceed without the elements being visible.

BUT if I create a normal release build or a Dev build then everything is there Images and styling.

Is there anyone here that can advise on how to fix this ? I had a look on the internet for a solution but couldn't find any and I did create a Ticket on Detox's GitHub https://github.com/wix/Detox/issues/3635But I am not sure when they will reply on that ticket